# all go routines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go, goroutine

I don't understand why the deadlock is occurring in this code. I've tried several different things to get the deadlock to stop (several different versions using WorkGroup). This is my first day in Go, and I am pretty disappointed so far with the complexity of fairly simple and straightforward operations. I feel like I'm missing something big and obvious, but all of the docs I have found on this are seemingly very different from what, to me, is a very basic mode of operation. All of the docs use primitive types for channels (int, string) not more complex types, all with very basic for loops OR on they are on the other end of the spectrum where the functions are fairly complicated orchestrations.

I guess I'm really looking for a middle of the road sample of "this is how it's usually done" with goroutines.

```
package main

import "fmt"

//import "sync"
import "time"

type Item struct {
    name string
}

type Truck struct {
    Cargo []Item
    name  string
}

func UnloadTrucks(c chan Truck) {

    for t := range c {
        fmt.Printf("%s has %d items in cargo: %s\n", t.name, len(t.Cargo), t.Cargo[0].name)
    }

}

func main() {
    trucks := make([]Truck, 2)

    ch := make(chan Truck)

    for i, _ := range trucks {

        trucks[i].name = fmt.Sprintf("Truck %d", i+1)

        fmt.Printf("Building %s\n", trucks[i].name)
    }

    for t := range trucks {
        go func(tr Truck) {

            itm := Item{}
            itm.name = "Groceries"

            fmt.Printf("Loading %s\n", tr.name)
            tr.Cargo = append(tr.Cargo, itm)
            ch <- tr

        }(trucks[t])
    }

    time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("Unloading Trucks")
    UnloadTrucks(ch)

    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never close the "truck" channel `ch`, so `UnloadTrucks` never returns.

You can close the channel after all workers are done, by using a WaitGroup:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
}()
UnloadTrucks(ch)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/1V7UbYpsQr