# WaitGroup deadlock (without error message)

Tags: go, deadlock

I encountered an issue when creating a couple of goroutines, using a `sync.WaitGroup` to bring everything together at the right moment.

Basically, I tried writing something like this:

```
//global var
var wg sync.WaitGroup

//say inside main:
ch1 := make(chan *MyStruct) // data we're after
ch2 := make(chan string) // only used for warnings
result := []*MyStruct{}
for p := range data {
    wg.Add(1)
    go processData(p, ch1, ch2)
}
wg.Wait()
close(ch1)
close(ch2)
for elem := range(ch1) {
    result = append(result, elem)
}
for warn := range(ch2) {
    log.Printf("%s" warn)
}
```

The goroutine function(s) would then look something like this:

```
//processData
func processData(p interface{}, ch1 chan *MyStruct, ch2 chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    data := &MyStruct{}
    data.raw = p
    //based on certain conditions, this can happen:
    if data.NeedsMoreProcessing() {
        wg.Add(1)
        go additionalProcessing(data, ch2)
    }
    ch1 <- data
}

func additionalProcessing(data *MyStruct, ch chan<- string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    if err := data.ExtraStuff(); err != nil {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintf(
            "Additional processing on element %d failed: %s",
            data.Id,
            err.Error(),
        )
        return
    }
    data.SetAdditionalInfo()
}
```

AFAIK, I call `wg.Add` correctly (before the start of the goroutine), and I know the routines will take a while (they use `http.get` calls etc...). I did not get the common *"fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"* error message at all.

Instead, it seemed that the `Wait` call never returned. The issue was resolved when I wrapped that call in a routine of its own, though:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch1)
    close(ch2)
}()
```

But other than that, everything was left as-is. Why is this, that it seems like we need to call `Wait` in a goroutine? In this case, I really don't see much of a difference. The routines in my particular case take a couple of seconds to complete, surely there's no risk of the routines completing before the `Wait` call, is there?

Comment: You're copying the WaitGroup value. `go vet` will catch these errors.

Comment: @JimB: I'll need to update the code, because I'm actually using a global `WaitGroup`. That, and I've looked at the question you linked as duplicate: Like I mentioned in the question itself: _I am **not** getting the all goroutines are asleep_ error message. I'm not getting any errors, it just looks like an infinite loop somewhere, somehow...

Comment: It is possible to create yourself a deadlock like this and not see the `all goroutines are asleep` error message, so that in itself is not an indicator of what the issue is. Now with the global WaitGroup however, your problem is that you're not receiving from the channels until after you call `Wait()`, and all the goroutines are blocked sending on the channels.

Comment: @JimB FFS, I just fixed that... didn't stop to think that my channels aren't buffering... Added a length to the make clause, now both approaches are working. I think adding the routine worked at first, because it actually caused the `range` loop on the channel to kick in, unblocking the channels, having the channels buffer all the results is better though, so I'll use that instead

Comment: Yes, and if you wanted the channels unbuffered, your attempt at Wait() in a goroutine itself is still a good pattern to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519546/all-go-routines-are-asleep-deadlock