# Working with two goroutines... and still getting a deadlock

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock

I have been trying to make this work without erroring:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "github.com/JJ/go-onemax"
    "sync"
)

type eval_chromosome struct {
    chromosome string
    fitness  int
}


// Check out https://gobyexample.com/command-line-arguments
var wg sync.WaitGroup 
func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    chromosomes := make( chan string, 100 )
    evaluated := make( chan *eval_chromosome, 100 )
    for i := 0; i < 100; i ++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            this_chromosome := random_chromosome( 10000 )
            chromosomes <- this_chromosome
        }()

        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            this_chromosome := <- chromosomes
            this_evaluated := &eval_chromosome{ chromosome: this_chromosome,
                fitness: CountOnes.Count( this_chromosome ) }
            evaluated <- this_evaluated
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
    i:= 1
    for result := range evaluated {
        fmt.Printf("%d => %d\n", i, result.fitness )
        i++

    }
    fmt.Println("Time ", time.Since(start).Seconds())
}

func random_chromosome( length int ) string {
    chromosome := ""
    for i:= 0; i  < length; i ++  {
        if ( rand.Float32() < 0.5 ) {
            chromosome+= "1"
        } else {
            chromosome+= "0"
        }
    }
    return chromosome
}
```

What this code does is generate random boolean strings, write them to a channel, with another channel reading the strings and counting the number of ones.

I have used a WaitGroup, incrementing it by one every time I call a goroutine, and using `defer` inside it. It does its job: arrives to the part where the result is printed, but then it says

```
100 => 5033
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /home/jmerelo/Tutoriales/go-now/code/src/count-many-ones/count-many-ones.go:44 +0x1bf
exit status 2
```

closing the channels also does nothing. Going unbuffered produces lots of errors. Changing the buffer size does nothing.

Any idea of what is going wrong here?

*Edit*: The example is a bit more complex than the one mentioned here: [all go routines are asleep - deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519546/all-go-routines-are-asleep-deadlock) . There are two channels, and that one is not using the WaitGroups as indicated in the answer checked above. In fact, as indicated above, closing channels was tested, but only *after* doing the reading, since I thought (wrongly) that closing channels effectively destroyed it. The answer provided by JimB was really helpful, though.

Comment: You never close `evaluated`, so that for-range loop never terminates

Comment: Wow, man. That did it. Thanks!